# To understand working of Cellular iPad+iPhone and number of sim cards required

Tags: iphone, ipad, sim, cellular-carriers, call

I am totally confused by iPad Cellular calling features.

If I put a sim card in iPad cellular, how do I make or receive calls in iPad since, there is no default dial app in iPad.

*Case 1:* 1 sim card: Doesn't work for me.

Suppose I have 1 sim card and I insert it in iPad Cellular. I can browse internet, but can't make phone call. And iPhone can't make calls either as it has no sim card.

I would have to download some Apps for iPad to make calls. Some apps don't work in some countries. **So which app is good for this scenario?**

*Case 2:*  2 sim cards: Works, but is this what iPad Cellular designed for?

1 sim card for iPhone and other sim card just for iPad for browsing internet. 1 phone number is wasted here. If I have to use Wi-Fi to browse internet by setting up iPhone hotspot, I would have bought a normal one instead of the Cellular version.

**I need to understand the working of Cellular iPad and number of sim cards required.**

Comment: Please don't be offended, but this is very difficult to understand.  Do you know someone fluent in English who could help you edit it?

Comment: Not offended. Just bought iPad cellular and realized it's useless to me. Offended by the product and could not come up with good english. Speechless! Called TMobile. I have to install WhatsApp to call/receive call. But, WhatApp can't be used in some country. Other App recommended by TMobile to make call in iPad cellular is 'Mood', which I could not find in AppStore. So, I have no reason to buy iPad cellular (I thought can browse and make call). WIFI is good enough.

Answer (score 2):

No. iPads just use SIM for data, not voice.

You would need to keep your SIM in your iPhone and use the forward calls and text feature for iCloud to receive and make calls and messages from the iPad through the iPhone. Also, look into WiFi calling on the iPad by enabling it in the carrier / phone section of your settings app on iPhone.

Comment: Thank you. I thought slide in sim card, and phone call and browse should work. I did not expect it's so complex to setup. It's ok for me, but not for non-tech people who does not even know 'settings' icon in iOS. It's impossible for them to maintain such iPad.

Comment: You’re right, there are lots of things to learn. The good news is here and apple guides can get you introduced to tips. https://support.apple.com/ipad  Same for iPhone, look for the ***getting started*** section online and the tips app on your devices.